# Parsing timestamp with timezone in java?

Tags: java, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm trying to parse a string of format timestamp with timezone obtained from a DB. The String is as follows :

```
   SimpleDateFormat mdyFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSZ");

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); 
    Date d1 = mdyFormat.parse("2014-04-01 15:19:49.31146+05:30");

    String mdx = sdf.format(d1);

    System.out.println(mdx);
```

Problem is, I get an error saying :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-04-01 15:19:49.31146+05:30"
    at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:357)
    at com.karthik.Timestampvalidate.main(Timestampvalidate.java:31)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 11):

You need to use `X` instead of `Z`:

```
SimpleDateFormat mdyFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSX");
```

See [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more info.

Note: only available in Java 7+.

Comment: Thanx a lot ! Its working. I guess I was looking at an older version of documentation.

Answer (score 5):

If you get to use the new JSR 310 date/time APIs in Java 8, you can use the `XXX` format to parse the timezone. You need three `X`s to get the specific colon-separated offset that you're using.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSXXX");
TemporalAccessor dateTime = formatter.parse("2014-04-01 15:19:49.31146+05:30");
// returns: {OffsetSeconds=19800},ISO resolved to 2014-04-01T15:19:49.311460
```